# The Derivatives Of A Function y'=f(x,y)

Tags: derivatives

I'm having problem in finding $y''''$ if $y'=F(x,y)=f$ and $y''=fx + ffy$. Any help on this?  I know that i will a multi variate chain rule since it is a function of two variables but i got confused later. what's the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Example calculations are given [on page 46 of Goursat](http://archive.org/stream/differentialequa028961mbp#page/n57/mode/2up), it really just amounts to applying the chain rule to $f(x,y)$.

Answer (score 0):

The calculations get rather intense.  I have mathematica code here:

http://www.math.missouri.edu/~stephen/num-methods/5.4.runge.kutta.nb